# How would I retrieve the latest 'x' number of posts from multiple Facebook users with the Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-fql, koala

I'm looking to be able to return a JSON list of posts from a set of Facebook users with the Koala gem either through FQL or the Graph API. Currently I'm using the batch function of Koala to make a call for the first 'x' number of items in from each user feed and then flattening the array and sorting by time. The issue with this is that I would like to be able to get the first 'x' number of items where it doesn't get 10 from each user but simply the 10 most recent posts from the users I queried so I can retrieve the next 10 from the feed akin to what you would expect from your own home feed.

This is what I currently have:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new
@access_token = @oauth.get_app_access_token
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@access_token)
artists = []
followings.each do |following|
  artists << following.artist
end
feed = @graph.batch do |batch_api|
  artists.each do |artist|
    feed | batch_api.get_connections(artist.facebook, "feed", {"limit" => "10"})
  end
end
feed.flatten!
feed.sort! { |x, y| y["created_time"] <=> x["created_time"] }
```

**EDIT**

I believe I've found one possible solution with FQL as follows

```
batch_api.fql_query("SELECT post_id, source_id, likes, actor_id, message, type FROM stream WHERE source_id IN(artist1, artist2...)")
```

But I am now returned the error

```
[#<Koala::Facebook::APIError: OAuthException: (#606) Queries for multiple source_ids require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission>]
```

The issue with this is that my application does not require someone to login with Facebook and so I cannot request a read_stream permission. Is there anyway the Facebook app itself can request this?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but there is a FB bug described [here](http://developers.connect.facebook.com/bugs/178722318901047?browse=search_4f2ffa0b0569c1467861706):

I think that there is nothing to do on your part to solve it.